# IIS Express routing is not working properly in Visual Sudio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, and when I run the solution by `IIS Express` and send a request to my methods with postman, it returns a **404 status code**. But when I run my solution using `dotnet command` in PowerShell, the app works properly and returns an **OK response**.

I think my code is correct because it works correctly when I run it with `dotnet command`, but I couldn't find a way to fix this problem.

I tried to change the SSL port in `launchSettings.json`, I tried to send request using both http and https, but none of them worked. Is there any problem with `IIS Express` or `Visual Studio` or what?

- **Here is my `launchSettings.json`**

```
    "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:6321/docs",
      "sslPort": 44444
    }
```

- **This is my `controller class`**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ContentManagerController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("add")]
        public ContentManagerResponse AddSlider([FromBody]RequestClass request)
        {
            //some code
        }
    }
```

The routes are http://localhost:6321/api/ContentManager/add and https://localhost:44444/api/ContentManager/add

Comment: Did you try setting your port to 0? `"sslPort": 0`. Still if you are specifying the port number, please keep in mind that it must be within 44300 - 44399 otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I tried what you said, but it didn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't the base URL be: `"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:6321/",` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your particular case was changing the base URL in the `launchSettings.json`.

```
"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:6321/"
```